# Efficient way to import a csv file into PostgreSQL from a C program

Tags: c, postgresql, csv

I've a very large number of files, each containing thousands of records, each having more than 150 fields, delimited by ",". And I need to import these files into a PostgreSQL table, which has the same number of columns as the file.  As these infinite number of files are keep coming from a remote server, I'm writing a C application to import these files into the database, and the application would run as a daemon.

I came up with two solutions:

**1.** Parse each record in the C program itself, storing each record in a `struct`, then inserting this struct into the database. This would be hard as each field in the CSV file is not of fixed length.

**2.** Let the PostgreSQL import the file on its own using `COPY $1 FROM '$2' DELIMITER ',' CSV`.

Solution 2 is tempting enough. My question is, would solution 2 be reliable and efficient as well? Every record of these files is important for me, I need to know exactly what records have failed (if any).

The documents say `PGRES_COPY_IN` would be returned for the `COPY` statement, but that would simply mean "Copy In (to server) data transfer started.", leaving it obscure whether the copy was successful or not. How can I make sure all records have been imported successfully, or find out exactly which records have been failed?

```
    const char      *param_vals[NPARAMS]
    const char      *insert_query = "COPY $1 FROM '$2' DELIMITER ',' CSV";

    /* connect and error checking */

    res = PQexecParams(conn, insert_query, NPARAMS, NULL, param_vals,
                    NULL, NULL, 0);


    if (PQresultStatus(res) != PGRES_COPY_IN) {
            syslog(LOG_ERR, "failed to import file %s to database: ", filename)
            PQclear(res);
            graceful_shutdown(conn);
    }

    /* now how to find out if all records are successfully imported? */
```

If there is any other solution, please let me know of it.

Comment: Regarding the first solution, strings of dynamic length is a long solved problem in C. But that's the least of your problems, because CSV files are *deceptively* simple. If your files have quoted strings or escaped characters, parsing them turns from trivial to very complex. Which is why you should almost never do their parsing yourself, but either let it be done by a library or if you have other tools, let them do it (i.e. your solution 2).

Comment: According to the docs, "After successfully calling PQputCopyEnd, call PQgetResult to obtain the final result status of the COPY command".